# Linq to entites (EF6) return latest records of each group using Row number in T-SQL server

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm using Linq to entities to get most recent updated record of each group. But actually when I checked in sql profiler my Ling query generated many sub-query so that It really take too much time to complete. To solve this performance problem, I already wrote native T-Sql mentioned below so that I'm looking for solution to use Linq query that entity framework is generating the same my query using **(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ...)** . Below is my sample data :

- **Parent and Child tables:**

[image: Parent child relationship]

- **Sample data of Parent and Child tables:**

[image: Sample data of Parent and Child tables]

- **Below is my query result:**

[image: My query result]

**TSQL query:**

```
WITH summary AS (
SELECT  a.ParentId 
       ,a.Name
       ,a.Email
       ,p.Created 
       ,p.[Status], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.ParentId
                             ORDER BY p.Created DESC) AS rk
  FROM Parent a
    LEFT JOIN Child p
        ON a.ParentId = P.ParentId
    )
SELECT s.*
FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk = 1
```

My sample C# using Linq:

```
using (DbContext context = new DbContext())
{
  return context.Parents.Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId)
                .Include(a => a.Childs)
                .Select(x => new ObjectDto()
                {
                  ParentId = x.ParentId,
                  Status = x.Childs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Created).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentId).Status,
                  ChildName = x.Childs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Created).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentId).ChildName
                })
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities will generate verbose (to put it nicely) SQL. I have seen queries that generate over 1000 lines of SQL (logging what EF generates can be instructive). However size of query does not necessarily mean it is slow. What is your current working C# code? What are you entity definitions? What is the query plan (and have you added any indexes yourself)?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I pasted wrong sql sample anyway I already updated my sql sample .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to improve your C# query:

```
using (DbContext context = new DbContext())
{
    return context.Parents.Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId)
                .Include(a => a.Childs)
                .Select(x => new ObjectDto()
                {
                  ParentId = x.ParentId,
                  Status = x.Childs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Created).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentId).Status,
                  ChildName = x.Childs.OrderByDescending(a => a.ChildName).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentId).ChildName
                })
               .ToList();
}
```

Firstly the `Include` call does nothing here as you're not just returning EF entities (and thus the lazy loading semantics don't apply).

Secondly: avoid the repeated subqueries with a `let` clause.

(Also the lambda passed to `FirstOrDefault` must be an error as it takes a `Func<T, bool>` which that isn't.)

Thus

```
using (DbContext context = new DbContext()) {
    return await (from p in context.Parents
                  where p.ParentId == parentId
                  let cs = p.Childs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Created).FirstOrDefault()
                  select new ObjectDto {
                       ParentId = p.ParentId,
                       Status = cs.Status,
                       ChildName = cs.ChildName                      
                  }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Otherwise it looks reasonable. You would need to look at the generated query plan and see what you can do with respect to indexing.

If that doesn't work, then use a stored procedure where you have full control. (Mechanical generation of code – without a lot of work in the code generator and optimiser – can always be beaten by hand written code).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Great, It works well and I checked performance between 2 Linq queries then found using let keyword that optimized the execution time saved nearly half-time than before. Thanks so much @Richard

Comment: @nvtthang LINQ to Entities SQL generator isn't very clever, but if you saw that bigger change from common sub-query elimination you probably need to check the indexing of your tables by checking the generated query plans.